# Count adjacent repeated elements in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I expect:

```
input = ["a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "c"]
output: ['a', '3', 'c', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '1']
```

My code:

```
lst = ["a", "a", "a", "c", "b", "b", "c"]

result = []
index = 0

while(index < len(lst)-1):
    count = 1
    result.append(lst[index])
    while(lst[index] == lst[index+1]):
        count += 1
        index += 1

    result.append(str(count))
    index += 1
    print("step: ", result)

print("result: ", result)
```

What I got:

```
step:  ['a', '3']
step:  ['a', '3', 'c', '1']
step:  ['a', '3', 'c', '1', 'b', '2']
result:  ['a', '3', 'c', '1', 'b', '2']
```

I could not count the last element correctly.

Here is another input:

```
['East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'North', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'North', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'North', 'North', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'South', 'South', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'North', 'North', 'East', 'East', 'South', 'South', 'South', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'West']
```

Comment: You are not catching the last element in any way

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking how to fix your code, right? Cause there's a better way to do this entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not accounting for the last item in the list because you are avoiding an index out-of-bound error in the evaluation of `lst[index] == lst[index+1]` by iterating over a range of one less than the length of the list with `while(index < len(lst)-1):`.

An easy workaround without having to duplicate the counting code after the loop is to unconditionally append a dummy item to the list first, and optionally pop it after the counting is done, if you still need the original list intact. The example below uses an instance of `object` as a dummy item because it helps make sure that the last evaluation of `lst[index] == lst[index+1]` would never be `True`:

```
lst.append(object()) # append a dummy item first
while(index < len(lst)-1):
    count = 1
    result.append(lst[index])
    while(lst[index] == lst[index+1]):
        count += 1
        index += 1

    result.append(str(count))
    index += 1
    print("step: ", result)

lst.pop() # add this line only if you still need the original lst for later use
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = []
for k, g in groupby(l):
    res.extend([k, str(len(list(g)))])
```

Output:

```
['a', '3', 'c', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '1']
```